# Using Linq when getting value from nested list

Tags: c#, linq

I need to set a variable's value to the value of a property that is nested in several Lists. Each list only has one item except for one list. I'm trying to do this:

```
var myValue = myListA[0].myListB[0].myListC[0].
              myListD.Where(x => x.Name == "Misc Expenses").myListE[0].price;
```

This produces a compile time error that says myListD does not contain a definition for myListE. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Where does `myListE` come from? What type does it belong to, and what are the types of the other values in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the .Where clause, you need to to .First() (or .ToList()) in order to apply the Where clause:

```
var myValue = myListA[0].myListB[0].myListC[0].
              myListD.Where(x => x.Name == "Misc Expenses").First().myListE[0].price;
```

Technically, though, you can replace that .Where with .First directly, too:

```
var myValue = myListA[0].myListB[0].myListC[0].
              myListD.First(x => x.Name == "Misc Expenses").myListE[0].price;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing. I didn't know you could use First() like you have in the second piece of code. That's interesting.

Comment: Or, preferably, `Single()`